# non-numeric argument to binary operator (errorbar) when running ggplot in a for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I am stuck trying to create ggplots in a for loop when I try to add corresponding errorbars

Dataframe to reproduce error:

```
FINAL_BIRDS=structure(list(Treatment = c("erythrocytes", "erythrocytes", "steroid", "steroid","saturated_carbohydrate", "saturated_carbohydrate", "unsaturated_carbohydrate", "unsaturated_carbohydrate", "control"), 
                           Sleep = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), 
                           stderr_area. = c(25.2419795929641, 14.9130357358005, 26.8118518761557, 10.0726607683124, 31.2843207910337, 
                                            12.1257884222765, 25.6371591089567, 19.2819746866121, 25.0891862104105), 
                           stderr_convex_hull_area. = c(47.2925074176382, 54.9644641679047,47.902530313873, 38.4682148026727, 59.235691895529, 
                                                        13.0445638906346, 34.1646485413064, 64.3496918069692, 46.3824137518226), 
                           stderr_solidity. = c(0.0173055524483047, 0.0299738382839415, 0.0111109163382894, 0.0256906757514238, 0.0383184031467805, 
                                                0.0201101581307241, 0.0317966622671069, 0.026641685951252, 0.0175635694617109), 
                           mean_area. = c(281.206098616, 307.847857263202, 289.652372512966, 313.926158961588, 228.580981650845, 
                                          277.434083621289, 212.823732276778, 268.723306954329, 261.635619956637), 
                           mean_convex_hull_area. = c(503.997742769278, 583.752222613032,532.459453592992, 538.54560438105, 
                                                      425.028542307996, 467.447197721035,411.644305637731, 523.653759424016, 484.365635850339), 
                           mean_solidity. = c(0.555418485236562,0.535021867782228, 0.542686645447222, 0.588389258540302, 0.583747393534253, 
                                              0.593427068141056, 0.505346818720391, 0.516443711837328, 0.527916732368975)), 
                      .Names = c("Treatment",  "Sleep", "stderr_area.", "stderr_convex_hull_area.", "stderr_solidity.", 
                                 "mean_area.","mean_convex_hull_area.","mean_solidity."), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have made a list to call my column headers in the forloop:

```
variables <- c("mean_area.","mean_convex_hull_area.","mean_solidity.")
stderror<- c("stderr_area.","stderr_convex_hull_area.","stderr_solidity.")
perfect<-mapply(c, variables, stderror, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

The for loop:

```
plot_list=list()
for(i in 1:length(perfect)){
  p= ggplot(data=FINAL_BIRDS, aes_string(x="Treatment",y=perfect[[i]][1], fill="Sleep"))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270, hjust = 1))+
    geom_errorbar(aes_string(ymin=perfect[[i]][1]-perfect[[i]][2], ymax=perfect[[i]][1]+perfect[[i]][2]), 
                  width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9))
  file_name = paste(paste(getwd()),"/",perfect[[i]][1], ".tiff", sep="")
  tiff(file_name)
  print(p)
  dev.off()

  while (!is.null(dev.list()))  dev.off()
}
```

Unfortunately I run into this error but cannot figure out why:

```
Error in perfect[[i]][1] - perfect[[i]][2] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

However, I do know the code is working because when I plot the stderror as ymin and mean as ymax it is showing the correct values. Only substraction and/or addition seem to be causing problems.

```
plot_list=list()
for(i in 1:length(perfect)){
  p= ggplot(data=FINAL_BIRDS, aes_string(x="Treatment",y=perfect[[i]][1], fill="Sleep"))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270, hjust = 1))+
    geom_errorbar(aes_string(ymin=perfect[[i]][2], ymax=perfect[[i]][1]), 
                  width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9))
  file_name = paste(paste(getwd()),"/",perfect[[i]][1], ".tiff", sep="")
  tiff(file_name)
  print(p)
  dev.off()

  while (!is.null(dev.list()))  dev.off()
}
```

I get working results as below, showing it knows what the values of my stderror and mean are.

[image: stderror plotted as ymin=mean and ymax=stderror]

Comment: Please make your code self-contained and check for typographical errors. `FINAL_BIRDS` is not created anywhere in your example. So we cannot run it. Also there are insufficient closing parentheses for your `geom_errorbar()`. As it stands we cannot run your example to recreate the error.

Comment: Thank you Cymon, I have made the proper changes to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this within `aes_string`:

```
perfect[[i]][1]-perfect[[i]][2]
```

This will be evaluated first into

```
"mean_area." - "stderr_area."
```

It will try to subtract two strings, and yield an error.

You need to construct the whole expression as a string, e.g.:

```
paste(perfect[[i]][1], '-', perfect[[i]][2])
```